# How to count the number of rows pertaining to a certain year within a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table (named trxItemdata) which contains over 40 columns and 60million rows. One of these columns, named ActivityDateDate shows the date/year associated with each CustomerID (another column in the table).

What I would like to do is find the number of rows for allocated to each year (2010,2011,etc), such that I get a table that looks like this in the results output:

```
Year    Number of Rows
2011    100
2012    10000
2013    10000000
```

I was looking into the following code but am not too familiar with group by clauses:

```
select count(*) from trxItemdata
group by year(ActivityDateDate)
```

However when I run this I get the following table but am not sure what it means:

```
No Column Name
33060000
27546960
2941697
```

Any help you could provide would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your query should not be generating an error like that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the query you have shown in your question. Please give us the actual query that is giving you an error.

Comment: I updated the question as I ran the query again and received the following table but not was not able to understand what the info meant.

Comment: You get the count per year, but you don't select the year, so there's no way to tell which row that belongs to which year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
select year(activityDateDate) as [Year], count(1) as [Number Of Rows]
from trxItemdata
group by year(ActivityDateDate)
order by year(ActivityDateDate)
```

Does your date column really have "DateDate"? :P

Comment: Not really sure why this got downvoted. It seems answer exactly the question posed by the OP. >.<

Comment: This is the solution I had in mind, I don't understand the -1, could the user that voted this down explain why?

Comment: I would imagine because the OPs originally query did *look* syntactically correctly.  Still I added the year to the select statement which is what the end result he wanted.  So I'm not really sure :/

Comment: I believe this works correct, shows the table I am requesting. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yep will do, I have to wait 3minutes to approve it

Answer (score 2):

Your query is not naming the column. Try this:

```
SELECT YEAR(ActivityDateDate) AS [Year],
       COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRows
FROM trxItemdata
GROUP BY YEAR(ActivityDateDate)
```